# Retrieve Input value from Action onClick in SemanticUI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

In React Semantic-UI, Input elements can be given a handy action button or icon as shown here:

http://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input/#variations-action-icon-button

Unfortunately, the documentation is really poor at explaining how the action can trigger a function. The question of how you're meant to do this was asked here:

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/1944

And the answer seems to be that you should use onClick on the icon or button. That would look something like this:

```
<Input
    action={{
        icon: 'play', onClick: (event,data)=>{console.log(data);}
    }}
    defaultValue="I bet you wish you could access this!"
/>
```

While that seems logical, it raises the question **how do you access the value of the input, when the data passed to the onClick function describe the icon instead of the input?**

Answer (score 16):

The way you are trying to do it, you would need to create a ref for the `<Input>` component and then from that target get the value. However, a better way to do this would be to control the Input's value in state instead. Then you can have a click handler function that gets the value of the input from state each time your button is clicked.

```
<Input
  action={{
    icon: "play",
    onClick: () => this.handleClick()
  }}
  defaultValue={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
/>
```

Here's a quick Codesandbox example showing how this would work: https://codesandbox.io/s/y3j4m703ov